# kthread stopped without running

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel

If I create a kernel thread with `kthread_run` then `kthread_stop` it immediately, the kernel thread might be stopped without running. I checked the source code of `kthread_run` and `kthread_stop` in Linux-5.4.73

```c
/**
 * kthread_run - create and wake a thread.
 * @threadfn: the function to run until signal_pending(current).
 * @data: data ptr for @threadfn.
 * @namefmt: printf-style name for the thread.
 *
 * Description: Convenient wrapper for kthread_create() followed by
 * wake_up_process().  Returns the kthread or ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM).
 */
#define kthread_run(threadfn, data, namefmt, ...)              \
({                                     \
    struct task_struct *__k                        \
        = kthread_create(threadfn, data, namefmt, ## __VA_ARGS__); \
    if (!IS_ERR(__k))                          \
        wake_up_process(__k);                      \
    __k;                                   \
})
```

```c
/**
 * kthread_stop - stop a thread created by kthread_create().
 * @k: thread created by kthread_create().
 *
 * Sets kthread_should_stop() for @k to return true, wakes it, and
 * waits for it to exit. This can also be called after kthread_create()
 * instead of calling wake_up_process(): the thread will exit without
 * calling threadfn().
 *
 * If threadfn() may call do_exit() itself, the caller must ensure
 * task_struct can't go away.
 *
 * Returns the result of threadfn(), or %-EINTR if wake_up_process()
 * was never called.
 */
int kthread_stop(struct task_struct *k)
{
    struct kthread *kthread;
    int ret;

    trace_sched_kthread_stop(k);

    get_task_struct(k);
    kthread = to_kthread(k);
    set_bit(KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP, &kthread->flags);
    kthread_unpark(k);
    wake_up_process(k);
    wait_for_completion(&kthread->exited);
    ret = k->exit_code;
    put_task_struct(k);

    trace_sched_kthread_stop_ret(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

It seems that the kernel thread should have been waken up before `kthread_stop` return, but it might not. I am really confused, could anybody help me?

My test code is as follows.

test1.c

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/spinlock.h> 

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct task_struct *t1;
static struct task_struct *t2;
static struct task_struct *t3;

static int func(void *__para)
{
    const char *msg = (const char *)__para;
    printk("%s %s\n", __func__, msg);
    /* Wait for kthread_stop */
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
        schedule();
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    }
    set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
    printk("%s %s return\n", __func__, msg);
    return 0;
}
static int __init start_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Thread Creating...\n");
    t1 = kthread_run(func, "t1", "t1");
    if (IS_ERR(t1)) {
        WARN_ON(1);
        return 0;
    }

    t2 = kthread_run(func, "t2", "t2");
    if (IS_ERR(t2)) {
        WARN_ON(1);
        return 0;
    }
    printk("Stopping t2\n");
    kthread_stop(t2);
    printk("t2 stopped\n");

    t3 = kthread_run(func, "t3", "t3");
    if (IS_ERR(t3)) {
        WARN_ON(1);
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
static void __exit end_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning Up...\n");
    if (IS_ERR(t1))
        return;
    printk("Stopping t1\n");
    kthread_stop(t1);
    printk("t1 stopped\n");

    printk("Stopping t3\n");
    kthread_stop(t3);
    printk("t3 stopped\n");
}

module_init(start_init)
module_exit(end_exit)
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += test1.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=`pwd`

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=`pwd` clean
```

The command to run

```sh
sudo insmod test1.ko
sudo rmmod test1
```

The dmesg of the first run

```
[10914.046211] Thread Creating...
[10914.046515] func t1
[10914.046530] Stopping t2
[10914.046531] func t2
[10914.046533] func t2 return
[10914.046538] t2 stopped
[10914.046555] func t3
[10938.895544] Cleaning Up...
[10938.895545] Stopping t1
[10938.895552] func t1 return
[10938.895561] t1 stopped
[10938.895562] Stopping t3
[10938.895566] func t3 return
[10938.895587] t3 stopped
```

t2 has executed before stopped this time.

The dmesg of the second run

```
[10940.775771] Thread Creating...
[10940.776109] func t1
[10940.776126] Stopping t2
[10940.776138] t2 stopped
[10940.776162] func t3
[10956.375606] Cleaning Up...
[10956.375607] Stopping t1
[10956.375613] func t1 return
[10956.375674] t1 stopped
[10956.375674] Stopping t3
[10956.375678] func t3 return
[10956.375697] t3 stopped
```

t2 stopped without running. But t1 and t3 which are not stopped immediately run before being stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer corresponds to Linux kernel version 5.4.)

The newly created kernel thread task executes the function `kthread` in "kernel/kthread.c". If all is well `kthread` calls the thread function referred to by the `kthread_run`'s (or `kthread_create`'s) `threadfn` parameter. However, the final test before calling the `threadfn` function pointer is to check the kernel thread's `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP` bit. If the `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP` bit is set, the `threadfn` function pointer will not be called and the new kernel thread task will call `do_exit` with the exit code `-EINTR`. The relevant piece of code at the end of function `kthread` is as follows:

```
    ret = -EINTR;
    if (!test_bit(KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP, &self->flags)) {
        cgroup_kthread_ready();
        __kthread_parkme(self);
        ret = threadfn(data);
    }
    do_exit(ret);
```

Although `kthread_run` wakes up the newly created kernel thread task before returning, it is possible for the `kthread_stop` function to be called and set the kernel thread's `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP` bit before the kernel thread reaches the final check of its `KTHREAD_SHOULD_STOP` bit prior to calling the `threadfn` function pointer. In that case, the kernel thread will exit without the `threadfn` function pointer ever being called.

OP's original code can be changed to print the return value of `kthread_stop` as follows:

```
    int exit_code;

    /* ... */
    printk("Stopping t2\n");
    exit_code = kthread_stop(t2);
    printk("t2 stopped, exit code %d\n", exit_code);
```

Then it should show that thread `t2` exited with code `-EINTR` (probably `-4`) if it was stopped before the entry function `func` was called.

Comment: I pass a pointer of ```struct completion entered``` to the ```threadfn```, and complete it at the beginning of ```threadfn```. The caller of ```kthread_run``` waits for the completion of ```entered```, then call ```kthread_stop```. Is that correct? My code is as follows.

Comment: It seems that comment is not a good place to paste code directly. So I pasted the code on github gist:
<https://gist.github.com/seekstar/4bdef2a775383d417e265317832e44ed>
Is there any other more efficient solution?

Comment: @searchstar The code looks fine, but if the `struct para` is on the stack of the function that called `kthread_run` (or `kthread_create`), then in the general case of stopping the thread after the function returns, the kthread entry function `func` should copy all the parameters it needs from `*para` before the call `complete(&para->entered);` and not use anything from `*para` afterwards. (For example, in your code, do `const char *msg = para->msg;`, then `complete(&para->entered);` and later on `printk("%s %s return\n", __func__, msg);`.)

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.